# siteConfig error in node activities boilerplate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node js. I'm trying to make a boilerplate application to integrate all social media streams from facebook, github and twitter into an aggregated news feed. I cloned the node activities bolierplate application and put in my facebook app key to test the app. On executing node server.js in the terminal I'm getting this error : [image]

/home/shiva/node-practice/FeedSort/lib/getConfig.js:10
        throw new Error('Could not load site config.')
        ^
Error: Could not load site config.
    at Object. (/home/shiva/node-practice/FeedSort/lib/getConfig.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object. (/home/shiva/node-practice/FeedSort/server.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

My siteConfig.js file is as follows : 
[image: siteConfig.js]

My code in text :

```
var settings = {
 'sessionSecret': 'sessionSecret'
 , 'port': 8080
 , 'uri': 'http://localhost:8080' // Without trailing /

// You can add multiple recipiants for notifo notifications
// , 'notifoAuth': null [
//  {
//      'username': 'shiva'
//      , 'secret': '12345'
//  }
// ]


// Enter API keys to enable auth services, remove entire object if they aren't used.
 , 'external': {
    'facebook': {
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        appSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
    // , 'twitter': {
    //  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    //  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    // }
    // , 'github': {
    //  appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    //  appSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    // }
 }

 , 'debug': (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
  settings.uri = 'http://yourname.no.de';
  settings.port = process.env.PORT || 80; // Joyent SmartMachine uses process.env.PORT

  //settings.airbrakeApiKey = '0190e64f92da110c69673b244c862709'; // Error    logging, Get free API key from https://airbrakeapp.com/account/new/Free
}
module.exports = settings;
```

**Edit: getConfig.js**

```
var siteConfig; 
try { 
    // Usually we check for siteConfig.js in project root. 
    siteConfig = require('../siteConfig'); 
} catch(e) { 
    try { // Looks for siteConfig in home dir, used for no.de 
        siteConfig = require(process.env.HOME+'/siteConfig'); 
    } catch(e) { 
        throw new Error('Could not load site config.') 
    } 
} 
module.exports = siteConfig;
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: can you share the `getConfig.js` code ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma Here's the code : var siteConfig;
try {
 // Usually we check for siteConfig.js in project root.
 siteConfig = require('../siteConfig');
} catch(e) {
 try {
  // Looks for siteConfig in home dir, used for no.de
  siteConfig = require(process.env.HOME+'/siteConfig');
 } catch(e) {
  throw new Error('Could not load site config.')
 }
}

module.exports = siteConfig;

Comment: as it states in error log - your position of siteConfig.json is not in the expected place. can you screenshot your directory/file structure of the project?

Comment: @shershen This is my directory hierarchy : https://www.anony.ws/image/JKWf

Comment: according to this, your filename is **siteConfig.sample.js**, not siteConfig.js